# Questions about model first MVC 3 using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, visual-studio-express

I was playing around with Entity based on this article in Visula Studio Express 2012: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685494.aspx

Had to completely re do this after some findings:

1. According to the article you can create database, this is correct but classes are not created unless you right click on an empty part in the diagram choose properties and select something for "code generating strategies" (I only had default). After that my project didn't build anymore because of errors. Trying to do it again an a newly created project didn't crate the model classes anymore (not sure what I did to make it work the first time).
2. After creating products in the diagram, create a database and then use that database in a second project to create models the products.cs file is created but without annotations (I had product name as 200 char max but it's not in the products.cs file).
3. After scaffolding controllers and views in the second project (making models from database created from models in the first project) the product name is incorrectly validated to 200 char max. Even though the designer shows 200 max the products.cs file is missing annotation.

If I am doing something wrong here could anyone explain to me how to create product.cs file from an Entity diagram and still be left with a buildable project?
Is it normal for model classes created from database to have no annotation (for example max 200 char field)?

I like Entity and the idea of it. Lots of documentation out there with videos but for now I'll go out and buy a hat because will pull all my hair out trying to get used to way it works :-)

Comment: I think you meant VS Express 2012

Comment: yes, I corrected. So far I have not been able to scaffold an update page that actually checks nullable or max lenght when using entity. Going to give up on this one, looks good in videos but doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's cool to create database with entity classes using the designer but creating the classes from the designer or from the database is not (yet) working properly.

No annotations so no checks for null or anything. I manually created the classes and added annotation for product name:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Product name"), 
  Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Name is required"), 
  StringLength(10)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Then right click controllers folder in solution explorer and choose => add => controller => using entity framework as a template to create crud views.

For some reason here I have to create a data context class that creates yet another connection string and database.mdf file but ... form validation works perfectly in JavaScript and on server.